Is it possible to cancel a forked subtask in a StructuredTaskScope
Kotlin coroutines let to cancel a coroutine:
suspend fun forgettingTheBirthDayRoutine() {
  coroutineScope {
    val workingJob = launch {
      workingConsciousness()
    }
    launch {
      delay(2000L)
      workingJob.cancel()
      workingJob.join()
      logger.info("I forgot the birthday! Let's go to the mall!")
    }
  }
}

The first time the workingConsciousness reaches a suspending point after the invocation of workingJob.cancel(), it will be canceled, as will its children's coroutines.
Is it possible to achieve the same behavior using structured concurrency in Java (StructuredTaskScope and its subclasses)?

No, it is a responsibility of StructuredTaskScope.Subtask itself, or technically, the Callable which is passed to fork method, to implement its cancellability. How in Java you can cancel  a thread? No way, only call interrupt for it and it is up to the thread's method run how to react on it. If you look at older FutureTask` it is along the same lines. How it is possible to cancel a task (or a thread) in Kotlin? What is under the hood of such feature?

It works because a coroutine is not a thread but an instance of a Continuation. In Java, the same is true for virtual threads. So, canceling a virtual thread means putting the underlying continuation in a proper state and letting the event loop of the carrier thread throw the CancelException or call the Thread.interrupt() method. At least, I hoped so...However, we do not have access to the started virtual thread.

Yes, you are right we don't have an access to Subtask's thread. But StructuredTaskScope.fork is not final method and we can implement our own Subtask  that support this cancellability. You might notice that Structured Concurrency is pretty new concept and may not provide all needed features at this point of time.  But it could be nice thing to implement, let me look at it and hopefully I could come with a solution. And just FYI, Structured Concurrency only indirectly related to virtual threads, it could be implemented over platform threads as well. Nice question, BTW.

Uhh, does not seem to be possible. I forgot that Subtask is a sealed interface.

Gosh, I hope they add it as a future feature

Hopefully they will add it in the future, yessir. Well, in fact, as we control this Callable , it might be possible to retrieve a current Thread it executes on and somehow pass it to StructuredTaskScope instance (maybe with ScopedValue) , but it will be far less elegant in comparison with custom implementation of  Subtask.

Can you show me this last solution?

Yes, sure. if I'll find a solution even minimally acceptable, I'll post it as an answer.

Given the example, are you looking to cancel a sub-task from another sub-task based on a certain timeout? I am trying to relate this to invoking scope.shutdown from your second task.

I don't want to shut down the whole scope. The other forked threads must continue with the execution.


No, a virtual thread is not some other programming language’s continuation. A virtual thread is a thread with all consequences. Like the possibility to run concurrently to the initiating thread on a different core and the ability to execute arbitrary code that might not give up the CPU until completion. 2) A structured task scope is not tight to virtual threads in any way. It may use virtual threads (and does so by default) but it doesn’t have to. Its features do not follow your wrong assumptions about virtual threads. It has the same possibilities to cancel a subtask as other frameworks.


@Holger, thanks for the clarification. Indeed, virtual threads use continuations under the hood. However, I agree with you: as they share the same interface as fat Threads, they must adhere to the same constraints.

@Holger, yeah, we discussed virtual vs platform threads in Structured Concurrency. More interesting question is do the Structured Concurrency masterminds think that task cancellability is against is its ideology or they just neglected such a feature, possibly for a preview version?

@igor.zh since a StructuredTaskScope is a tool for managing jobs executed by threads, not so much different to an ExecutorService, the same solutions for cancellation will work. E.g. a typical implementation of submit will wrap the callable into a FutureTask and pass that FutureTask to the execute method. You can do (almost) the same with StructuredTaskScope, wrap the job and fork that wrapped job. Then, you can cancel the FutureTask at any time. Still, the job is not a coroutine and will only stop executing when interruption is supported.

@Holger, igor.zh answered. However, interrupting a virtual thread interrupts its carrier thread. :( I guess it's still impossible to implement this feature with the current version of VT, which lacks this form of cooperative scheduling.

That’s not a problem. The carrier thread will clear the interruption state before starting to execute a different virtual thread. That’s similar to canceling the task of a thread pool executor; this will interrupt the worker thread, which also must clear the state before starting to process a different task (in fact, it’s exactly the same, as this logic has been recycled by executing virtual threads atop an existing thread pool implementation).

The only known for me way to cancel a task in Java is to invoke thread.interrupt for this thread. That's exactly the way java.util.concurrent.FutureTask implements its cancel method - it plainly attempts to interrupt the thread which executes  its Runnable/Callable.
So, to attempt to cancel a StructuredTaskScope.Subtask we just need to interrupt a thread it executes on (or is executed by). However, as the OP correctly said, such a thread is not accessible for StructuredTaskScope users.
To make this thread accessible the ideal solution would be to implement (possibly via delegation) StructuredTaskScope.Subtask interface, storing the thread reference and extending it with cancel method. This is, however, impossible to do because this interface is sealed.
To circumvent this obstacle and assuming that we could have a control over the Callable argument, passed to StructuredTaskScope.fork method, we could have the following delegation:
class CancellableCallable<V> implements Callable<V> {

    private final Callable<V> delegatee;
    private Thread thread;

    public CancellableCallable(Callable<V> delegatee) {
        this.delegatee = delegatee;
    }

    @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        return delegatee.call();
    }

    public Thread getThread() {
        return thread;
    }

}

then, if the exact type of Callable, passed to fork method, was CancellableCallable, it would be possible to cancel such a SubTask:
((CancellableCallable<?>) subtask.task()).getThread().interrupt();

As a convenience we could have a subclass of StructuredTaskScope (which is permitted and even advisable) that wraps the above in a cancel method:
class CancellableTaskScope<T> extends StructuredTaskScope<T> {

    public <U extends T> void cancel(Subtask<U> task) {
        if (task.state() != Subtask.State.UNAVAILABLE) 
           throw new IllegalStateException("Task is not running");
        final Callable<? extends U> callable = task.task();
        if (callable instanceof CancellableCallable) {
            ((CancellableCallable<?>) callable).getThread().interrupt();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Task is not constructed with CancellableCallable");
        }
    }

}

It is easy to see that the above does not provide atomic cancelling like FutureTask does, so there could be an attempt to interrupt already terminated thread, which might be quite OK, as Thread.interrupt's JavaDoc states: Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.
The usage of the above might look like following:
try (CancellableTaskScope<String> scope = new CancellableTaskScope<>()) {
    Subtask<String> subtask1 = scope.fork(new CancellableCallable<>(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SOME_INTERVAL);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return "OK";
    })); 
    Subtask<Integer> subtask2 = scope.fork(...);            
    scope.cancel(subtask1);
    scope.join(); 
} 

Notice that, as usual, the burden of reaction on the thread interruption is solely on the task itself, Callable implementation. Native methods are known to ignore it. That's why the word attempt is used above intentionally. In tat respect, FutureTask, is no different, of course.
EDIT in response to OP's request.
@Holger suggested to use FutureTask for constructing a Callable, passed to fork method. This employs the full power of FutureTask, atomically set cancellation flag, for example. Then the snippet above will look like this:
try (StructuredTaskScope<String> scope = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
    FutureTask<String> task1 = new FutureTask<>( ()-> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(SOME_INTERVAL);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return "OK";
    }); 
    Subtask<String> subtask1 = scope.fork( () -> {
        task1.run(); 
        return task1.get();
    }); 
    Subtask<Integer> subtask2 = scope.fork(...);            
    task1.cancel(...);
    scope.join(); 
} 


Woah! Your solution is mind-blowing! I'll play with it a bit and then give you feedback. Thanks a lot!

I looked at the actual implementation of the interrupt() method for a virtual thread. It interrupts the carrier thread, which is not good. I guess @Holger was right.

Sure, please do. In fact, it is most trivial way, but it is not me, but sealed SubTask to blame :-1:

In the world of coroutines, canceling a coroutine just puts the continuation in a CANCELLED state, which means it is no longer scheduled by the runtime. The pool of threads remains intact. Moreover, the coroutine cancelation happens only when the coroutine reaches a suspension point (cooperative scheduling).

Instead of implementing this CancellableCallable, you could use FutureTask in the first place; you just have to submit it like scope.fork(() -> { task.run(); return task.get(); }); because StructuredTaskScope requires a Callable instead of a Runnable.

That's true, @Holger is perfectly right, and that way is even preferable. But you anyway have to somehow unwrap FutureTask from SubTask  to get all beauties of the former, right?

In my example scope.fork(() -> { task.run(); return task.get(); }); you already have a reference to the FutureTask in task and can keep it there. In principle, you do not need to keep a reference to the SubTask then, as querying the state and result is also possible with FutureTask. It’s just a different API, so if there’s a method requiring you to pass in a SubTask, you’ll need to keep both. You can create a record holding both; it’s also possible to create a utility method for creating it (which may also be in a subclass of StructuredTaskScope as in your example).

@Holger, agree if you don't want to have a reference to a SubTask, but only to FutureTask, then yes, there is no need to wrap. I think SubTask does offer some useful service, but you could keep both. All in all, no more than a matter of convenience.

@igor.zh, your solution works as expected! Kudos! Can you change it to FutureTask?

Great! You mean to what @Holger suggested here and here?
